# in python unit test using vcr, can we use one function to generate different cassettes files?

Tags: python, vcr

[vcrpy](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy) is the python record/play package, below is the common way from the guideline

```
class TestCloudAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_api_token(self):
        with vcr.use_cassette('fixtures/vcr_cassettes/test_get_api_token.yaml'): 
            # real request and testing

    def test_container_lifecycle(self):
        with vcr.use_cassette('fixtures/vcr_cassettes/test_container_lifecycle.yaml'):
```

I want to have different record files, so I have to repeat this in every method.

Is it possible to have one line somewhere to simplify this like:

```
TEST_CASE_VCR(USE_METHOD_AS_FILENAME)
class TestCloudAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_api_token(self):
        # real request and testing
    def test_container_lifecycle(self):
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported in newer versions of vcrpy by omitting the cassette name altogether. From the documentation:

> VCR.py now allows the omission of the path argument to the use_cassette function. Both of the following are now legal/should work

```
@my_vcr.use_cassette
def my_test_function():
...
```

> In both cases, VCR.py will use a path that is generated from the provided test function’s name. If no
>   cassette_library_dir has been set, the cassette will be in a file with the name of the test function in directory
>   of the file in which the test function is declared. If a cassette_library_dir has been set, the cassette
>   will appear in that directory in a file with the name of the decorated function.
>
> It is possible to control the path produced by the automatic naming machinery by customizing the
>   path_transformer and func_path_generator vcr variables

Comment: That's great. How do you customize path_transformer?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a feature to do this currently built in to VCR, but you can make your own.  [Check out the decorator that Venmo created.](https://venmo.github.io/blog/2014/04/30/vcrpy-at-venmo/)

Comment: Could you add a few relevant details from the article to your answer? Link only answers are frowned upon since there is a risk the link will become unavailable, which would make the answer no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

This gets a lot easier with `vcrpy-unittest` which is--as you might guess--integration between `vcrpy` and `unittest`.

Your example becomes this:

```
from vcr_unittest import VCRTestCase

class TestCloudAPI(VCRTestCase):
    def test_get_api_token(self):
        # real request and testing

    def test_container_lifecycle(self):
        # real request and testing
```

and the cassettes are automatically named according to the test and saved in a `cassettes` dir alongside the test file. For example, this would create two files: `cassettes/TestCloudAPI.test_get_api_token.yaml` and `cassettes/TestCloudAPI.test_container_lifecycle.yaml`.

The directory and naming can be customized by overriding a couple methods: `_get_cassette_library_dir` and `_get_cassette_name` but it's probably not necessary.

`vcrpy-unittest` is on github at https://github.com/agriffis/vcrpy-unittest and PyPI at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vcrpy-unittest